# Is wp-cli now officially on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I doubt this will be controversial, but I figured someone should ask what the community consensus would now be. :)

Our current position on wp-cli is probably well summed up in [this post by Rarst](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4291/46066):

> While WP CLI is not explicitly on topic, we tend to allow questions about it because of it's unique role as related to WP project and infrastructure.

However, Matt Mullenweg [has today announced](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/12/28/supporting-the-future-of-wp-cli/) that wp-cli is now part of WordPress.org:

> The website of wp-cli.org, the code / GitHub, Twitter, and such are all coming in under the WordPress.org umbrella

Of note, a recent questioner [ran into some problems](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/appropriate-content) when asking about wp-cli, and we've previously had confusion about the [disambiguation between Automattic and WordPress.org](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/what-are-first-party-plugins/), so I thought it would be a good idea to get a clear answer on where wp-cli now stands so we can point people to this in future.

So the question is: is wp-cli now on-topic for WPSE?

Comment: I'ld vote for 100% yes! For me it always was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say unless there is any movement to *change* how we currently treat such, bringing it into a core project does make it explicitly on topic here.

As per earlier discussions you refered to — it was de–facto treated as on–topic anyway, so I don’t see any issue with transition. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with questions being asked about wp-cli, don't thinks there are that many that even if none of them will be answered the amount of noise added will make any difference, and it is an important server admin tool.

That said, I am skeptical about the usefulness of that, as none of its core developers is around here, and therefor the answers that will be given will probably based on the basic documentation available on the project's site, and more advanced questions will still be better served by asking at wherever the new support forum will be. .... same issues basically as with all plugins and themes.

Comment: Good point in your second para. We don't need core devs around to help others but at least users of it. I use it regularly, but I haven't delved into the code much. I don't know how many other users we have.

Comment: @TimMalone, yeh, I was aiming there for question like "how do I add support in my plugin for a wp-cli command" or "how do I add new commands". No need for the (only) core developer for that, but do need to have people with the experience of doing such things, or at least familiarity with the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

So far I do not believe (, read or understand) from the *Make.WP* post that there is anything else than a financial/ sponsoring involvement from *Automattic(?)s* side with *WP CLI*. They do not overtake the project. Still, our stance is clear: It's crucial to have a CLI tool in a development context and we have always had it **in scope**.

Having financial backup to help a project sustain will not change our scope regarding *WP CLI*. And from looking at the questions around it and the quality level of answers there is no reason to change the scope … unless the community puts it on a vote in a separate meta question and votes against it.